# A question on rotation transformations?

Tags: geometry

So I have these questions...
[image]

and these are the answers...
[image]

Now I can see that they have used the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ where $\theta$ goes in $e^{i\theta}$ but otherwise I can't see the logic in this, I haven't been given any formulas to say what $z$ or $z'$ is equal to? Are they using $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Sorry if this is basic stuff but this lecturer struggles to even get that across to us?

Comment: Take the polar form : $z'=(i)z$ is of the form $r'e^{i\theta'}=(1e^{i \tfrac{\pi}{2}})re^{i \theta}$ $\iff r'=1r \ \& \ \theta'=\tfrac{\pi}{2}+\theta + k2 \pi$, which is the description of a $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started ...

You probably know that any complex number can be written in "polar" form:
$z = re^{i\theta}$. Then, if $z = pe^{i\alpha}$ and $w = qe^{i\beta}$, we have
$$
zw = (pq)e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}
$$
Further explanation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division_in_polar_form). So, in particular, suppose $z = re^{i\alpha}$, and consider the complex number
$$
z' = z \, e^{i\theta} = r e^{i(\alpha+\theta)}
$$
We see that $z'$ has the same magnitude as the original $z$, but $\arg(z') = \alpha +\theta = \arg(z) + \theta$. In other words, $z'$ is obtained by rotating $z$ through an angle $\theta$ around the origin. This means that the mapping $z \mapsto z \, e^{i\theta}$ performs a rotation by an angle $\theta$ around the origin.

Comment: Thank you for the well worded explination, so for my second question, how did they implement the rotation about $i$ instead of about $0$?